# If $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $-\Delta u=f$, with $f\in C^{\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$, then $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary, $n\geq2$. Schauder regularity theory says:

> If $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $-\Delta u=f$, with $f\in C^{\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$, $0<\alpha<1$, then $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$.

I want to ask about the following attempt of proof. Extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $f|_{\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\bar{\Omega}}=0$. Consider the fundamental solution $$\Phi(x)=C\log|x|,\;\;n=2;\quad\quad  \Phi(x)=C\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}},\;\;n\geq3.$$
Let $$v(x)=\int_\Omega\Phi(x-y)f(y)\,dy=(\Phi\ast f)(x),\;x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
The idea is to show that $v\in C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ from $f\in C^{\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$.

My questions:

1. Why does proving that for $v$ give $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$?
2. Trying to prove $v\in C^1(\bar{\Omega})$, if we derivate under the integral sign we have $$\partial_{x_i}v(x)=C\int_\Omega \frac{x_i-y_i}{|x-y|^n}f(y)\,dy.\quad (*)$$ But, how is it justified that it can be derivated under the integral sign? I see that $\frac{x_i-y_i}{|x-y|^n}\in L^1(\Omega,dy)$, but to derivate under the integral one would need to bound $|\frac{x_i-y_i}{|x-y|^n}|\leq g(y)\in L^1(\Omega,dy)$. I think $(*)$ is true in the distributional sense, but that is not useful to prove $v\in C^1$.
3. For the second derivatives, the same problem: formally, $$\partial_{x_i,x_j}u(x)=\int_\Omega\left(\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-y|^n}-\frac{n(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\right)f(y) \,dy,$$
   but I do not see how this can be justified.

My doubts 2 and 3 came from reading from page 3 [here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.08f/lec05.pdf).

Comment: Why should the extension of $f$ belong to $C^{0,\alpha}$? Consider, e.g., $f \equiv 1$.

Comment: @gerw You are right. Edited.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your "Schauder regularity theory"? I doubt that it is true. Consider, e.g., the usual L-shape domain with $f = 1 \in C^\alpha(\bar\Omega)$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$. However, the solution $u$ does not belong to $C^2(\bar\Omega)$.

Comment: @gerw I don't exactly know... My two professors wrote on the blackboard the statement in yellow... Do you think it should be $f\in C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$ with compact support in $\Omega$ or something like that? I don't find the correct statement for the Laplacian.

Comment: @gerw Or should we impose $\partial\Omega$ smooth?

Comment: In the light of the L-shape domain, I would say that we need some regularity of $\Omega$.